# Pass argument in shellscript after creating exe with pyinstaller

Tags: python, logging, window, pywin32, servicemanager

Below is my shellscript:

```
& 'C:\files\service_file.exe' install 


#Start the windows service
& 'C:\file\service_file.exe' start --env "D:\full_project\device\config\windows.env"
```

I used pyinstaller to create service_file.exe and 'start' arg is working fine but does not support env path if included

I get path not found error, even after giving the env.

below is my service_file.py

```
import os
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import servicemanager
import argparse

class MyService:
    def stop(self):
        self.running = False

    def run(self):
        application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
        os.chdir(application_path)

        def load_env(envFile):
            global env_obj
            env_obj = Environment(envFile)
            return env_obj

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="testing")
        parser.add_argument("--env")
        parser.add_argument("--log")
        args = parser.parse_args()
        env_obj = load_env(args.env)

        db_agent(env_obj)
        db_agent_download(env_obj)

        client_agent(env_obj)
        init_scheduler()

        app = rest_api(env_obj)
        app.run(port=env_obj.rest_api_port, host="0.0.0.0")


class MyServiceFramework(win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = 'DeviceAgent'
    _svc_display_name_ = 'Device Agent Service'

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        self.service_impl.stop()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOPPED)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        self.service_impl = MyService()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_START_PENDING)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        self.service_impl.run()


def Main():

    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("this is if")
        servicemanager.Initialize()
        servicemanager.PrepareToHostSingle(MyServiceFramework)
        servicemanager.StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()
    else:
        print("this is else",sys.argv)
        win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(MyServiceFramework)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

What should i do ? how can i run the shellscript along with env.
I want to know how i should pass the argument for env

Comment: I don't see `start` in your argument parser code...

Comment: Hi @alec_djinn Im using shellscript to pass the argument. you can see the 'start' there.

Comment: Why do you pass `start` as first argument then? Please, share the shell code as well. From what you have posted, it is unclear what `start` does

Comment: @alec_djinn Actually that is the full shescript code in script.sh, upto my knowledge start need to be given at first to start the service in the windows services

Comment: Is the script working as intended when you run it with Python? `python service_file.py --env ...`

Comment: @alec_djinn Yes, its working and if i remove the --env and leave with only start (gave path as static inside code without arg), then also working fine. but only if i include --env with start as above then --env not working.

Comment: Then it is not a Python problem, but one related with the windows shell. Unfortunately I can't help with that.

Comment: @alec_djinn Hey thanks for your time ! NP, Hope I get some help from somebody.